# Get all DVD drives in Java

Tags: java, file, cross-platform, dvd

[After getting a list of the drive roots](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listRoots%28%29), is there a cross-platform way in Java to check whether any of the drives is:

- A DVD drive
- ...that contains a disk?

I want the user to be able to select a DVD for playing, and narrowing the options down to DVD drives rather than including other drives (such as pen drives, hard drives etc.) would be helpful in this case. If I can get a list of such drives, showing what ones contain disks would again be helpful (same reason.)

After searching around though I haven't found any way to do this that doesn't involve platform-specific hackery. Is there anything out there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new [file system API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) in Java 7 can do this:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();

for (Path rootPath : fs.getRootDirectories())
{
    try
    {
        FileStore store = Files.getFileStore(rootPath);
        System.out.println(rootPath + ": " + store.type());
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println(rootPath + ": " + "<error getting store details>");
    }
}
```

On my system it gave the following (with a CD in drive D, the rest hard disk or network shares):

```
C:\: NTFS
D:\: CDFS
H:\: NTFS
M:\: NTFS
S:\: NTFS
T:\: NTFS
V:\: <error getting store details>
W:\: NTFS
Z:\: NTFS
```

So a query on the file store's *type()* should do it.

With a CD not in the drive, the getFileStore() call throws

> java.nio.file.FileSystemException: D:: The device is not ready.

Comment: Bit of a hack though, really. But it's good for identifying immediately playable drives. However,  wouldn't like to use it for permanently displaying a drive.

Comment: This isn't cross platform. On Linux using EXT4, the output is:
/: rootfs

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Linux-compatible approach:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.getDefault();

for (FileStore store : fs.getFileStores()) {
    String storeString = store.toString();

    String type = store.type();
    if (type.equals("tmpfs")) {
        continue;
    }

    if (storeString.startsWith("/dev")) {
        continue;
    } else if (storeString.startsWith("/proc")) {
        continue;
    } else if (storeString.startsWith("/sys")) {
        continue;
    } else if (storeString.startsWith("/run/") && !storeString.startsWith("/run/user")) {
        continue;
    }

    int index = storeString.indexOf(" (");
    if (index < 0) {
        continue;
    }

    String path = storeString.substring(0, index);

    System.out.printf("%-30s %-20s %-10s\n", path, store.name(), type);
}
```

It can only detect a *disk*, not a *drive*. With no disk inserted, or a corrupted disk, the mount point just disappears.

```
    /                              /dev/sda5            btrfs     
    /boot/efi                      /dev/sda1            vfat      
    /mnt/oldubuntu                 /dev/sda3            ext4      
    /home                          /dev/sda4            ext4      
    /run/user/1000/gvfs            gvfsd-fuse           fuse.gvfsd-fuse
    /run/user/1000/doc             portal               fuse.portal
    /media/zom-b/W1200A            /dev/sdb1            ext4      
    /mnt/nasu                      zom-b@192.168.1.20:/ fuse.sshfs
    /media/zom-b/MovieDataDVD001   /dev/sr0             iso9660
```

Optical disks can be `iso9660` or `udf` afaik